# issue in storing time in javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

That is what I have tried but I need the time that the data is generated, but "now" is the current time of the system!

but "now" is the current time not the time that the data was generated. Any idea of what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
var obj = {
     time: Date.now(),
     value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the value when try to access it

something in these lines

```
 var obj = {
         time: 

function updateData(a) {
     var obj = {
         time: (function() { return new Date(Date.now() - duration);})() ,
         value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
     };
     a.push(obj);
}
```

Wrap it up in a IIFE (Immediately invoked Function Expression) that returns the current date.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. but I am not sure where and what to edit. Should I write updateDate in initialise()? and I should also edit updateDate?

Comment: You can have the updateDate method like the one above. And you don't need to move the updateDate method into initialize.. Just Use this instead in initialize `obj= { time : new Date().now`